# Use WHERE statement in OVER()

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a query, which will give me a row_number for all the returned records. I can do that for all records present in the database. The problem is, i need to somehow retrieve a row number for a query with WHERE statement inside (`WHERE posts.status = 'published'`).

My original query looks like that:

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, 
    row_number() over (ORDER BY posts.score DESC) as position 
FROM posts
```

However, adding a where statement inside `over()` throws syntax error:

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, 
    row_number() over (
        WHERE posts.status = 'published' 
        ORDER BY posts.score DESC
    ) as position 
FROM posts
```

Comment: Just add the WHERE at the end of your first query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.*, row_number() over (ORDER BY posts.score DESC) as position 
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.status = 'published'
```

Comment: The thing is i don't want to display only "published" posts. I want to display ALL posts in the DB but retrieve their position in "published" query, not ALL query.

Comment: If so; what do you expect for a value on "position" for non-published rows? null? Then just this a sub-query to add the column to all the records.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are after. Maybe show an example of expected output. Here is an an example of an approach:

```
create table posts(id int, score int, status text);
insert into posts values(1, 1, 'x');
insert into posts values(2, 2, 'published');
insert into posts values(3, 3, 'x');
insert into posts values(4, 4, 'x');

SELECT x.id, x.score, x.status
      ,CASE WHEN x.status = 'published' THEN null ELSE x.position END
  FROM (SELECT posts.*,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY posts.score DESC)
               -SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'published' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                  OVER (ORDER BY posts.score DESC) as position
          FROM posts
       ) x
```

Result:

```
4  4  x         1
3  3  x         2
2  2  published
1  1  x         3
```